# JQuery - add/remove forms and divs

Tags: asp.net, jquery, forms, html, replace

I'm sure I've seen examples somewhere before, but I can't seem to find them. I have a page which has 5 buttons. I'd like each button to load up a different form, without refreshing. I could use UpdatePanels, but it sounds overkill for this (and bandwidth-costly). I'd like to load all the forms in one go, so clicking through the buttons essentially hides/shows the relevant forms. I can't do this using the `html()` method (as-is) since the forms can be quite complicated and contain ASP.NET controls which postback to the server. Instead, I've put the forms in individual `divs`.

I tried doing something like this:

```
                case "button1":

                    $(".current_form").show();
                    $("#divForm1").prependTo($('.current_form'));
                    break;

                case "button2":

                    $(".current_form").show();
                    $("#divForm2").prependTo($('.current_form'));
                    break;
```

The problem with this is that the old form always remains there, rather than being replaced. 
Is it possible to attach a `div` to a given container in JQuery? Or is there another method which may be better?

Thanks for any help

**full code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").button();
        $("button").click(function() {

            switch ($(this).attr("value")) {
                case "button1":

                    $('.current_form').empty().show();
                    $("#divForm1").clone().prependTo($('.current_form'));
                    break;

                case "button2":

                    $('.current_form').empty().show();

                    $("#divForm2").clone().prependTo($('.current_form'));
                    break;




            }
            return false; //prevent postback
        });



    });

</script>
```

I'm testing with these divs:

```
<div class="current_form">
<div id="divForm1" >

 This is div 1

</div>
</div>


<div class="current_form">
<div id="divForm2" >

  This is div 2

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it like this instead:

```
$('.current_form').empty().show();
$("#divForm1").clone().prependTo($('.current_form'));
```

Your markup would be like this:

```
<!-- Possible <form> tag here -->
<div class="current_form"></div>
<!-- Possible </form> tag here -->
<div id="divForm1">
 This is div 1
</div>
<div id="divForm2">
  This is div 2
</div>
```

This clears out the form before, and it creates a **copy** of what you want to prepend to put in `.current_form`, this means the original is still left and your buttons won't stop working after the first use.

Be sure to have your `<div id="divFormXX">` elements outside the submitted form so the values from the original don't get submitted to the server as well.

---

**Update:** better option, less markup and less javascript :)
Markup:

```
<div id="divForm1" class="form" style="display: block;">
 This is div 1
</div>
<div id="divForm2" class="form">
  This is div 2
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("button").button().click(function() {
    $(".form").hide();
    $("#divForm" + $(this).attr("value").replace('button','')).show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.form { display: none; } //Hide the forms initially
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the method, and I think I'm a bit closer. The background of the `current_form` shows up , but it's blank. If I remove the `empty()` method, then the forms show up, but it keeps adding to it instead of replacing it.

Comment: @superexsl - That shouldn't be happening, perhaps a missing break somewhere, can you post the full code?

Comment: @superexsl - Updated the answer, is moving the markup around like that possible?  An alternative is to give the `divFormXX` elements a class `.form` or something, and just hide/show those, would be a much simpler approach if that's an option, let me know if it is and I'll post an example.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is new markup, so feel free to do whatever you think would be best. I tried the code, and it works, but it seems to be creating a duplicate copy on the side of the screen. (But only once)

Comment: @superexsl - Added an entirely new option, much simpler overall, it displays the `#divForm1` element by default on load, just remove that style if that's not desired.  Instead of moving elements all around, this just hides and shows things so only a single one is visible at a time, which seemed to be what you're after...let me know if not.

Comment: That's perfect, Nick! Thanks for all the help, it's much appreciated.